# GCP Load Balancer: 502 Server Error, “failed_to_connect_to_backend” over "HTTP2"

Tags: apache, google-cloud-platform, load-balancing, http2

I am trying to get the Google load balancer working over HTTP2.

At the load balancer backend, I have an apache2 server running, which is accessible over both HTTP1.1 and HTTP2, when hit directly.

Load balancer protocol is configured as "HTTP2". When I am trying to reach apache server via load balancer over HTTP2 , I am getting 502 error (with curl and on browser both). And in the google logs I can see *failed_to_connect_to_backend* error.

I have also set the firewall rule that allows traffic from 130.211.0.0/22 and 35.191.0.0/16 over port 443 to reach instance at backend.

Comment: Is the backend-service configured correctly? I mean, does it work with HTTP1.1?
"failed_to_connect_to_backend" usually means that the backend-service is nor correctly configured.

Comment: yes, it is working as expected with HTTP1.1.

Comment: Can you share the LB details? Remember that HTTP2 requires TLS configured. When you change the protocol to HTTP/2, the load balancer is expecting to receive HTTPS responses. Another thing yo can look at is if the named ports are correct.